# HTML5 website using CSS, background and header issue

Tags: css, html, background, web

I am worknig on my css page trying to place a background image around my website to bring more of a nice look to the overall project. In the css I included the background in the body, but as you can see it does not display on the website. I am confused as in why?
Below is CSS and the project website:

```
#header {text-align: center;}

#body { background-image:url('backgroundflower.jpg');}


#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
     background-color: #FAFAFA;
     color: #003300;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

#h2 {text-align: center;}

#container {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #container div {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        #header {}

        #left,
        #center,
        #right {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }

        #center {font-family: Josefin Slab; background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 494px;
        } 

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

#right { font-family: Josefin Slab;}

#left a {text-decoration: none;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
         color: #FFFFCC;
         font-weight:bold;
         border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
         padding: 5px;}

figure{}

#left a:link { background-color: #003366; }
#left a:visited { background-color: #48751A; }
#left a:hover {border: 3px inset #333333; }

#left ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }

#footer { text-align: center; font-family: Audimat; background-color: #E1F5A9;
    clear: both; }
```

http://younani.com/finalsite/finalindex.html

Also, I made a customer banner and when I try to place in  where it says Younani flowers, it will just stretch and actually go above the header, doesn't fit. Is there a better way of placing an image for h1? If any more coding is needed to being provided let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have treated the body as an ID by putting a hash in front of it.

```
#body { background-image:url('backgroundflower.jpg');}
```

It should be:

```
body { background-image:url('backgroundflower.jpg');}
```

Comment: oh you guys are right! I just fixed that and now the background is actually on the back of the website, would I need to place it in the container?

Comment: If you only want the image to appear in the `#container` rather than the body then yes.

Comment: Alright, great. Also, the image multiples is there a way of turning that off? Like for example, either centering or stretching it to just 1 picture?

Comment: You can stop the repeating by using `background-repeat: no-repeat;` and you can position it in the center using `background-position: center center ;`

Comment: Got it. It's centered, but it doesnt cover the whole area, is it possible to cover it?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But it uses CSS3 and is not supported by all browser versions. `background-size: cover;` is the property. But you would need to put browser prefixes in to cover as many versions as possible. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS makes a reference to `#body`, but there is no element with an ID attribute of body.

You should remove the `#` and update that line of CSS to:

```
body { background-image:url('backgroundflower.jpg');}
```